# ajax not loading content in DOM

Tags: php, javascript, dom

instead of populating the "tempDiv" in html, the print.php is loaded showing the content. The same code is working for other files and javascript functions. :/

HTML:

```
 <li><a class="button black" href="#searchbox" onclick="viewall()" >View All</a></li>
 <li><button class="button black" type="submit" form="selectcol" onclick="printDiv()"></button></li>
      <div id="searchresults"  style="padding-top:30px; padding-bottom:10px; max-height:280px; ">
     The results will show up here..!!
     </div>

  <div id="tempDiv"></div>
```

The viewall() function :

```
function viewall(){

var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  /*
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("searchresults").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }*/



  xmlhttp.open("POST", "viewall.php", true);            // set the request
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");            // adds  a header to tell the PHP script to recognize the data as is sent via POST
  xmlhttp.send();       // calls the send() method with datas as parameter

  // Check request status
 // If the response is received completely, will be transferred to the HTML tag with tagID
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
      document.getElementById("searchresults").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

}
```

The printDiv() function called to print the selected columns:

```
function printDiv()
{

var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  /*
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("searchresults").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }*/



  xmlhttp.open("POST", "print.php", true);          // set the request
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");            // adds  a header to tell the PHP script to recognize the data as is sent via POST
  xmlhttp.send();       // calls the send() method with datas as parameter

  // Check request status
 // If the response is received completely, will be transferred to the HTML tag with tagID
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
      document.getElementById("tempDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }



}
```

PHP :

```
<?php

$col = $_POST['print'];

$flds = "";
foreach($col as $value){

if(isset($col)){
if($flds !="") 
$flds .= ",";
$flds .= $value;
}

}

$sql = "SELECT ". $flds." from student";



$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","university") or die("could not connect". mysqli_error($con));
$rs = mysqli_query($con, $sql);


echo "<table border='1'";

while($r = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){

                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td class='searchtabledata'>".$r[0]."</td>";
                            echo "<td class='searchtabledata'>".$r[1]."</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";

                }                           



?>
```

the result i get on clicking the submit button

[image]

Comment: You mean its loading the PHP code into the DOM?>

Comment: usually the ajax loads content in a selected element in the DOM using the innerHTML etc.
But, here in my case, print.php is loaded into the DOM and the echo statements simply put the data on the blank page instead of loading it into the tempDiv

Comment: k..lemme edit the question..adding the html

Comment: @AkashGupta although the table seems to be echoing in the screenshot you sent. Am I missing the <tbody> </tbody></table> tags ? I don't see them in your php or js.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you define the readystate function before sending the request?

part 2. It looks like your printdiv function submits a form. You should be able to remove the form tags if you are using a strictly AJAX procedure. You'll need to adjust a few other things to make that work.

Comment: although a good practice as long as the state he is looking for is 4, the order doesn't matter..

Comment: that doesn't make a difference bro.. :/

Comment: Which part of my answer?

Comment: the readystate part..well i agree with part 2, but i need to pass the selected fields to the PHP file, thats why i used the form along with the ajax. Is there any other way to pass the selected fields to the PHP file through ajax.

Comment: i am using `$col = $_POST['print'];` to access the selected checkboxes , is there any other way to access these selected checkboxes through AJAX, to that i can remove the form tags ?

Comment: Yeah, you can't do both. It's the submit that reloads the page. You need to send one or more key-value pairs in the send() method. Be sure to [edited] encodeURI() the values first. Get the values of your form elements using document.getElementById.